# Excel crashing when using PasteSpecial

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the following code to read some data from a webpage and then pasting is into a sheet. I do this process twice (i.e. for 2 webpages) in the same sub. However, when using pastespecial for the second time, Excel crashes and I have no idea why this happens.

```
Sub main()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Dim inputEl As HTMLInputElement

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer

    'open website
    ie.navigate "http://...website.../page1.html"
    ie.Visible = False
    Sleep 5000
    While ie.Busy
        DoEvents
    Wend

''now copying source code to excel
Set doc = ie.document
CopyText doc.body.innerHTML

Sheet3.Activate
Sheet3.Cells.Clear
Sheet3.DrawingObjects.Delete
Range("A1").Select
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

'opening second page
ie.navigate "http://...website.../page2.html"
Sleep 2000
While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
Set doc = ie.document

Sheet8.Activate
Sheet8.DrawingObjects.Delete
CopyText doc.body.innerHTML

Range("A1").Select
'''''Excel crashes after this point, specifically on the next line
Sheet8.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

End Sub
```

For reference, I used a function CopyText (borrowed from internet) which is defined below:

```
Public Sub CopyText(Text As String)
    Dim MSForms_DataObject As Object
    Set MSForms_DataObject = CreateObject("new:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
    MSForms_DataObject.SetText Text
    MSForms_DataObject.PutInClipboard
    Set MSForms_DataObject = Nothing
End Sub
```

I tried using this as well but didn't help - [pastespecial Crashing when pasting excel data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218623/pastespecial-crashing-when-pasting-excel-data)

Comment: Try switching the two URLs around.  If your code then starts crashing in the first part of the code, it is probably due to a difference in the webpage.  (If it continues to crash in the same spot, it is probably your code.)

Comment: I assume the object you are creating in CopyText must do something special, which is why you can't do something as simple as `Sheet8.Range("A1").Value = doc.body.innerHTML`?

Comment: If I use range.value=html then it will put in the entire html code into one cell. what i want is to imitate ctrl+v so that when the html code is pasted into the sheet, it appears like a webpage. this way i will be able to use usual excel tactics to read various parts of the webpage

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Sheet8.Paste` instead or try just `Sheet8.Range("A1").PasteSpecial` without any parameters.

The paste special dialog is different when the clipboard contains data that is not from your current Excel application.

Comment: i tried both, sheet8.paste doesn't work, still crashes and range.pastespecial doesn't crash but also doesn't paste anything. I checked and the clipboard still had the string/data. Also, I don't understand why it works for the first time in the same SUB and not the second time.

Comment: Does it work if you paste it manually? If you record a macro of pasting text, the code looks like this `ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False` and I don't see any other problem in your code.